# React Navigation - Jumping between tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hello guys I have 5 Containers in my tab bar and I would like to know if there is an option to return to the main screen if I select another tab container.

So I have the following

https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/stacks-in-tabs-v3

While I am in `Home` tab I click on `Go to Details` and then I switch to `Settings` tab. If I return to `Home` container I want to see the default screen which is `HomeScreen`

Any option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine the `tabBarOnPress` of the `navigationOptions` of each `StackNavigator` like so:

```js
const stacks = [
  { Home: HomeScreen, Details: DetailsScreen },
  { Settings: SettingsScreen, Details: DetailsScreen }
].reduce((stacksObj, stack) => {
  const initialRoute = Object.keys(stack)[0];
  stacksObj[initialRoute] = createStackNavigator(
    stack,
    {
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => navigation.navigate({
          routeName: initialRoute,
          action: navigation.popToTop()
        })
      }
    }
  );
  return stacksObj 
}, {});

export default createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator(
  stacks,
  { /* same defaultNavigationOptions as the snack example */ }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause your `DetailScreen` is nested in stack `Home`, you must navigate one more level to that screen

```js
  _navigateHome = () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'Home',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }),
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }
```

Comment: So where do I have to call `_navigateHome`?

Comment: when you press button Home in `SettingsScreen`

Comment: well my idea was not to go from there but from tabs. So while in `Home` tab I am in `Details` screen I jump to `Settings` tab from tabs bar and from there I select `Home` tab from tabs bar

Answer (score 0):

Looks the api has changed , the new way to achieve this is :

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.navigate({
    name: 'Profile',
    params: {
      user: 'jane',
    },
  })
);
```